# Roman Numeral Converter In Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5, roman-numerals

I have been programming for around 4 months now. Mainly JavaScript, However, I am now moving onto Swift and Java.

I am struggling to implement an appropriate for-in statement to create a calculator which converts numbers to roman numerals. ( I have done it in JS).

Thing's I have done:

- Created two arrays
- Created the input and out variable
- Created a function which takes an Int input and String output
- Created a for-in loop to loop through the numbers

Where I am stuck is running the loop through the numbers to find the roman numeral

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var inputNumber = 0
    var outputNumeral = ""

    var numberValue = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1]
    var romanNumeral = [
      "M",
      "CM",
      "D",
      "CD",
      "C",
      "XC",
      "L",
      "XL",
      "X",
      "IX",
      "V",
      "IV",
      "I"
    ]

    func converter(inputNumber: Int) -> String {
        for numb in numberValue {
            while numberValue[0] < numb {
                romanNumeral + outputNumeral
                numb - numberValue[0]
            }
        }

        return outputNumeral
    }    
}
```

Comment: `romanNumeral` is an array of String. `outputNumeral` is a String. You can't add an element to an array with `+` Use `append` if that's really what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, which works for 1 to 4999

```
let initial = 1980
var val = initial
var countForRoman : [(rom: String, num: Int)] = []    // how many occurences of romanNumbers; don't use dictionaries as not ordered

for (index, number) in numberValue.enumerated() {
    let x = val / number
    if x > 0 {
        countForRoman.append((romanNumeral[index], x))
        val = val - x * number
    }
}
print(countForRoman)    // Just to see how it converted

var romanString = ""
for pairs in countForRoman {
    let iter = pairs.num
    for _ in 1 ... iter { romanString += pairs.rom }
}

print(initial, "in roman is", romanString)
```

Example with 1980:

```
[(rom: "M", num: 1), (rom: "CM", num: 1), (rom: "L", num: 1), (rom: "X", num: 3)]
1980 in roman is MCMLXXX
```

If you want to go beyond 4999 (here up to 399 999):

```
var numberValue = [100_000, 90_000, 50_000, 40_000, 10_000, 9000, 5000, 4000, 1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1]
var romanNumeral = [
    "(C)",
    "(X)(C)",
    "(L)",
    "(X)(L)",
    "(X)",
    "M(X)",
    "(V)",
    "M(V)",
    "M",
    "CM",
    "D",
    "CD",
    "C",
    "XC",
    "L",
    "XL",
    "X",
    "IX",
    "V",
    "IV",
    "I"
]


let initial = 9999
var val = initial
var countForRoman : [(rom: String, num: Int)] = []    // how many occurences of romanNumbers; don't use dictionaries as not ordered

for (index, number) in numberValue.enumerated() {
    let x = val / number
    if x > 0 {
        countForRoman.append((romanNumeral[index], x))
        val = val - x * number
    }
}
print(countForRoman)    // Just to see how it converted

var romanString = ""
for pairs in countForRoman {
    let iter = pairs.num
    for _ in 1 ... iter { romanString += pairs.rom }
}

print(initial, "in roman is", romanString)
```

To get

```
[(rom: "M(X)", num: 1), (rom: "CM", num: 1), (rom: "XC", num: 1), (rom: "IX", num: 1)]
9999 in roman is M(X)CMXCIX
```

For 39999

```
[(rom: "(X)", num: 3), (rom: "M(X)", num: 1), (rom: "CM", num: 1), (rom: "XC", num: 1), (rom: "IX", num: 1)]
39999 in roman is (X)(X)(X)M(X)CMXCIX
```

For 129_999

```
[(rom: "(C)", num: 1), (rom: "(X)", num: 2), (rom: "M(X)", num: 1), (rom: "CM", num: 1), (rom: "XC", num: 1), (rom: "IX", num: 1)]
129999 in roman is (C)(X)(X)M(X)CMXCIX
```

Just encapsulate this code in the convert Function and you get it.

Comment: That is fantastic! and a whole load to take in. Thank you!

Comment: Great you appreciate.I've improved code so that you can now count up to 4_000_000, with dual notation: parenthesis and super-lined. Plus conversion from roman to numeral with tests to check roman string consistency.